# How do I change the order of display of additional fields associated to an External column?

Tags: 2010, column, content

In SharePoint 2010 I have an External Data Column that I have linked to an External Content Type with 5 fields named A,B,C,D and E. I have selected all fields to be shown when the external data column is used and by default when I use the external data column in a view they are appearing in alphabetical order of field name. This isn't necessarily the order a person would like to view them in.

How do I change the order in which the fields are displaying?

I understand I can (ask the ECT provider to) rename the fields but that's a bit clumsy. is there another way?

Comment: Silly me. I've just realised I can use the "positions from Left" in the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your List page, from the Ribbon select `List` and then `Modify View` (next to Create View). It will list the columns currently in the list, which you can re-order using the drop down boxes.

A nice feature here is that if you select a number already occupied, it will shift all the other columns along one.

If you want to change the name of the fields displayed to the user, you'll need to modify the view in SharePoint Designer, it doesn't seem possible from the base user interface.